generate *.story.ts automatially when generating Angular component by cli
I'm considering using Storybook in Angular project. I want to generate story file for each component, but it is bothersome to make story file manually. So I want to generate story file automatically when I generate component. For that, I can restrict component generation from the cli.(ng generate component)
This is problem about command. So Angular schematics or script in package.json may be relevant.

You can achieve this by creating a custom Angular schematic that generates both the component and the corresponding Storybook file.
Here's a step-by-step guide:

First, install the necessary tools for creating schematics:

npm install -g @angular-devkit/schematics-cli


Create a new schematic project:

schematics blank --name=my-component-storybook


Navigate to the schematic project:

cd my-component-storybook


Open the my-component-storybook folder in your code editor. You will see a collection.json file. This file is used to tell the Angular CLI what schematics your collection provides.

Update the collection.json file to include a schematic for generating a component:


{
  "$schema": "../node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/collection-schema.json",
  "schematics": {
    "my-component": {
      "description": "Create a component and its corresponding Storybook file",
      "factory": "./my-component/index#myComponent"
    }
  }
}


Create a new folder named my-component in the src folder. Inside the my-component folder, create an index.ts file. This is where you will define the schematic.

In the index.ts file, import the necessary modules and define the schematic:


import { Rule, SchematicContext, Tree, url, apply, template, mergeWith, SchematicsException, chain } from '@angular-devkit/schematics';
import { strings } from '@angular-devkit/core';

export function myComponent(options: any): Rule {
  return (tree: Tree, _context: SchematicContext) => {
    const sourceTemplates = url('./files');
    const sourceParameterizedTemplates = apply(sourceTemplates, [
      template({
        ...options,
        ...strings
      })
    ]);
    return mergeWith(sourceParameterizedTemplates);
  };
}


Create a new folder named files in the my-component folder. Inside the files folder, create your component and Storybook files with placeholders for the dynamic parts:

// __name__.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '<%= dasherize(name) %>',
  templateUrl: './<%= dasherize(name) %>.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./<%= dasherize(name) %>.component.css']
})
export class <%= classify(name) %>Component {}

// __name__.component.stories.ts
export default {
  title: '<%= classify(name) %>',
  component: <%= classify(name) %>Component,
};

export const <%= classify(name) %> = () => ({
  component: <%= classify(name) %>Component,
});


Build the schematic:

npm run build


Link the schematic to make it available globally:

npm link


Now you can use your custom schematic to generate a component and its corresponding Storybook file:

ng generate my-component-storybook:my-component my-component-name

This will generate a new component with the name my-component-name and a corresponding Storybook file.
Remember to replace my-component-name with the actual name of your component.

Since I can not comment to what Petros said, I would like to mention that what he said is not enough. If you try to run the ng generate command using my-component schema it will complain that there is no argument named name.
For the schematic to work with a name argument you need to create schema.json file in my-component folder with the name parameter:
 {
   "properties": {
     "name": {
       "type": "string",
       "minLength": 1
     }
   }
 }

and then you need to update the collection.json file to include a reference to that schema file:
{
  "$schema": "../node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/collection-schema.json",
  "schematics": {
    "my-component": {
      "description": "Create a component and its corresponding Storybook file",
      "factory": "./my-component/index#myComponent",
      "schema": "./my-component/schema.json"
    }
  }
}

and then you can run the command:
ng generate my-component-storybook:my-component --name=my-component-name

